# Why did I get: gdata: Unable to load perl libaries

Tags: r, perl

I'will generate a beamer presentation slide with that code snip:

```
\section{PLK alle Mandanten und alle Fachbereiche}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{PLK alle Mandanten und alle Fachbereiche}
  \begin{figure}
   <<echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, out.width='\\textwidth', out.height='0.8\\textheight'>>=
    # Run source code to create scatter plot
    source("/bit_repositories/tm-plk/02_Analysis/GraficClientsDepartments.R")
    @ 
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

In the pdf prsesntation I'm getting this errror message:

```
gdata: Unable to load perl libaries needed by
read.xls()## gdata: to support 'XLX' (Excel 97-2004)
files.#### gdata: Unable to load perl libaries needed by
read.xls()## gdata: to support 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+)
files.#### gdata: Run the function
'installXLSXsupport()'## gdata: to automatically download
and install the perl## gdata: libaries needed to support
Excel XLS and XLSX formats.#### Attaching package:
'gdata'#### The following object is masked from
'package:stats':#### nobs#### The following object is
masked from 'package:utils':#### object.size
```

Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much.
Sebastian

Comment: What could possibly be unclear about the error message? It even tells you something to do to install perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the function

```
'installXLSXsupport()'
```

then try to install gdata again.

If that doesnt work see this:
[install gdata help page on cran](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/INSTALL)

Comment: OK, this is what I've made. 1. installXLSXsupport(perl = "perl", verbose = FALSE) than I get this error message: Unable to install Perl XLSX support libraries. 
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\perl.exe" "C:/Users/Sebastian Sukstorf/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/gdata/perl/install_modules.pl"' had status 2